# Ubuntu and Django, no module named 'django'

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

I have a problem with Django on Ubuntu. When I type `python` in terminal, terminal returns

`Python 3.4.1 (default, Jun  2 2015, 15:13:43) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux`

so it's allright. When I type `admin-django.py version` terminal returns `1.8.2`

so it's still allright. But when I go with

`python`

> `import django`

terminal returns:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'`

I'm fighting with it whole day, I'm quite new to linux. Do you know any solution?

Comment: how did you install django? did you use `pip`?

Comment: @jamylak yes, I used pip install Django==1.8.2

Comment: `admin-django.py` is on system PATH but after you run python interpreter it looks like django is not on your `PYTHONPATH` - as you may know it's not the same.

Comment: @d-system ok, I got it. Would you tell me how to add django to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: sudo pip3 install Django solved whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general case I recomend you to start working with virtual environments. It is a very easy tool to manage diferent projects with their respective dependencies.

After opening the terminal. Type:

```
$virtualenv 'name of your virtual environment'
$cd 'name of your virtual environment'
$source bin/activate
```

Afterwards you could use pip install with no trouble.

I recommend you the following blogpost:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/